# How to retrieve Index-Fillfactor from Postgresql Catalog tables?

Tags: postgresql

Am trying to load Postgres attributes from its catalog tables.

I have created a Postgres table and few set of indexes(unique index, clustered index).
With the below query I could the Name of the index, type of the index as well as its comments.

```
SELECT c.relname  as indexname, i.indisunique as isUniqueIndex, i.indisclustered as isClustered, pg_catalog.obj_description(c.oid, 'pg_class') as COMMENT 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace  
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_index i ON i.indexrelid = c.oid 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class t ON i.indrelid   = t.oid 
WHERE c.relkind = 'i' and n.nspname = 'schema1' AND t.relname='table_with_index'
```

Is there a way to retrieve the `fillfactor` value of the index?
I'm using Postgresql 8.4 and I see the syntax for creating Index with fill factor, so hope there could be a way to get the value from the catalog tables.

Answer (score 1):

A decent method is to run psql with the "-E" option to echo the catalog queries, then extract what you need from that.
Eg. `psql -d your_db -E` then issue `\d+ <your index name>`

An alternative query if you are looking for the index defintion is to use the `pg_get_indexdef()` function.

Eg.

```
select pg_get_indexdef('aaa_idx'::regclass::oid);
                         pg_get_indexdef                          
------------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE INDEX aaa_idx ON aaa USING btree (x) WITH (fillfactor=60)
```

I went ahead and extracted a catalog query from 9.2 which may or may not work in 8.4. It has been a while since I worked with the 8.4 catalogs and I can't recall if the tables referenced here have changed.

```
SELECT c.relchecks,
       c.relkind,
       c.relhasindex,
       c.relhasrules,
       c.relhastriggers,
       c.relhasoids,
       pg_catalog.array_to_string(c.reloptions || array(SELECT 'toast.' || x FROM pg_catalog.unnest(tc.reloptions) x), ', ') as storage_options,
       c.reltablespace,
       CASE
           WHEN c.reloftype = 0 THEN ''
           ELSE c.reloftype::pg_catalog.regtype::pg_catalog.text
       END,
       c.relpersistence
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_class tc ON (c.reltoastrelid = tc.oid)
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace nsp ON nsp.oid = c.relnamespace
WHERE nsp.nspname = 'schema1'
AND c.relname = 'YOUR INDEX'
```

Comment: Thanks for this help....am also looking for little more information from the index, which are available from the pg_get_indexdef() function. But that is in string, which needs parsing. Is there a different query to get the column order of the index as well... as I have asked the same above. Thanks.